# How to check if dictionary value present in list and replace

Tags: python-3.x

```
nounphrase = ['At the same time, other ncp1 arose, such as computers made by DEC, ncp2 , mainly 
               for use by businesses.']

res_dict = {'rep_sentence': 'At the same time, other ncp1 arose, such as computers made by DEC, 
                             ncp2 , mainly for use by businesses',
            'replacements': [{'replacedPhrase': 'desktop systems and workstations',
                              'replacement': 'ncp1'},
                             {'replacedPhrase': 'Sun, and SGI', 'replacement': 'ncp2'}]}

for each_rep in res_dict['replacements']:
    res = [masked_nounphrase for masked_nounphrase in noun_phrase if each_rep['replacement'] in 
            masked_nounphrase]
    final_result = [sub.replace(each_rep['replacement'],each_rep['replacedPhrase']) for sub in 
                    res] 
    print(final_result)
```

I want to check res_dict values `ncp1` and `ncp2` in nounphrase , if found, relace it with its replacedPhrase key. With above code snippet i am able to replace only one key and i am getting below ans:

```
['At the same time, other desktop systems and workstations arose, such as computers made by DEC, ncp2 , mainly for use by businesses.']
```

Comment: I want to check res_dict values "ncp1" and "ncp2" in nounphrase , if found, relace it with its replacedPhrase key.


With above code snippet i am able to replace only one key and i am getting below ans..
['At the same time, other desktop systems and workstations arose, such as computers made by DEC, ncp2 , mainly for use by businesses.']

Comment: What should be the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be, update the `str` with the modified value of the list `noun_phrase`:

```
s = ''
for elem in res_dict['replacements']:
    s = "".join([x.replace(elem['replacement'], elem['replacedPhrase']) if elem['replacement'] in x else x for x in noun_phrase])
    noun_phrase = [s]
print(s)
```

OUTPUT:

```
At the same time, other desktop systems and workstations arose, such as computers made by DEC, Sun, and SGI , mainly for use by businesses.
```

Comment: IT is getting failed for